# injecting singletons using typhoon giving multiple instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I have assembly as follows and it will initiate from plist

```
@implementation classAAssembly
- (id)classA {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[classA class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
               definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
           }];
}
```

when app load this creates instance and inject into relevant places

then I have some static methods need to use this, so I tried as bellow

```
+ (void)staticMethod {
      classAAssembly *assembly = [[classAAssembly new] activate];
      classA *classA = [assembly classA];
}
```

issue is when i do this it gives new instance, what i expecting is same instance created when app load.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new assembly above. What you need to do is get a handle to the [one created using plist integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself). So for example to access the assembly from your app delegate, inject it into that.

To access the assembly from a static method, you'll have to create a static pointer to it:

```
- (void) typhoonDidInject {
    myStaticAssembly = this.assembly
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the promt reply, actually my situation like this. i am not injecting classA to classB which contains static method, so I want to access the assembly initialized in app load using plist. is there any way or inbild function in typhoon to get it statically  ? 

@Jasper Blues